# multiple definition of

Tags: c, компиляция

Сделал вроде все нормально, но вот ругается

В проекте 4е файла:

**main.c**

```
/*

Программу подготовил: Буренков Игорь (М8О-206Б-17)

Вариант: АВЛ-дерево

*/
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* Системные библиотеки */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Пользовательские библиотеки */
#include "AVL_tree_slimrg.h"
#include "settings_slimrg.h"

/* Структуры */


/* Сигнатуры функций */
unsigned short int InputFiller();              // Ввод и исполнение комманд
void PrintError(unsigned short int ErrorCode); // Вывод ошибок



/* Основной цикл */
int main(){

    // Переменные
    unsigned short int log_error; // Код ошибки

    // Считываем и выполняем команды
    log_error = InputFiller();

    // Выввод ошибки
    PrintError(log_error);

    // Пауза при закрытии
    if (debug_pauseonclose) system("pause"); 

    // Все ОК
    return 0;
}

// Цикл ввода и выполнения
unsigned short int InputFiller(){

    // Переменные
    char tmpchar[StringLengthPS+1];                 // Временный контейнер для символа
    char tmpword[StringLengthPS+1];   // Временный контейнер для слова (массива символов)
    unsigned long long int tmpkey;    // Временный контейнер для ключа
    unsigned char errorcode;          // Код ошибки
    unsigned int i;                   // Тикер (для циклов и т.д.)

    // Создание пустого дерева
    struct avltree* AVLTree1 = AVL_Create();

    // Пока возможно - считываем первый символ строки
    while (scanf("%s", tmpchar) >= 1){
        // Перевод в нижний регистр
        tmpchar[0] = tolower(tmpchar[0]);
        // Определение комманды
        switch (tmpchar[0]) {

            // Добавить слово
            case '+':
                // Считываем слово
                scanf("%s", tmpword);
                // Преобразование в нижний регистр
                for (i = 0; i < StringLengthPS; i++) tmpword[i] = tolower(tmpword[i]);
                // Считывание ключа
                scanf("%llu", &tmpkey);
                // Довавляем лист (с включенным выводом)
                AVL_InsertLeaf(tmpword, tmpkey, AVLTree1, true);
                break;

            // Отладочные комманды
            case '!':
                // Считываем слово
                scanf("%s", tmpword);
                // Перевод в нижний регистр
                for (i = 0; i < StringLengthPS; i++) tmpword[i] = tolower(tmpword[i]);
                // Распознание слова
                if (strcmp(tmpword, "exit") == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else
                if (strcmp(tmpword, "print") == 0) {
                    AVL_PrintMe(AVLTree1);
                } else
                if (strcmp(tmpword, "save") == 0) {
                    AVL_SaveTree(AVLTree1, true);
                } else
                if (strcmp(tmpword, "load") == 0) {
                    AVL_LoadTree(AVLTree1, true);
                }
                break;
            // Удаление слова
            case '-':
                // Считываем слово
                scanf("%s", tmpword);
                // Преобразование в нижний регистр
                for (i = 0; i < StringLengthPS; i++) tmpword[i] = tolower(tmpword[i]);
                // Удаляем лист
                AVL_RemoveLeaf(tmpword, AVLTree1, true);
                break;
            // Заглушка
            case '\n':
                break;
            // Осталось слово
            default:
                for (i = 0; i < StringLengthPS; i++) tmpchar[i] = tolower(tmpchar[i]);
                // Поиск
                tmpkey = AVL_FindMe_p(tmpchar, AVLTree1, true);
                break;


        }
    }
 return 0;
}

// Печать ошибок
void PrintError(unsigned short int ErrorCode){
}
```

**AVL_tree_slimrg.h**

```
#ifndef AVL_tree_slimrg_h
#define AVL_tree_slimrg_h

// Стандартные заголовки
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

// Настройки
#include "settings_slimrg.h"

// Сама структура
struct avltree;

// Создание дерева
struct avltree* AVL_Create();

// Уничтожение дерева
void AVL_FreeAndNil(struct avltree* AVL_Tree);

// Проверка на пустоту
bool AVL_IsEmpty(struct avltree* AVL_Tree);

// Добавить лист
void AVL_InsertLeaf(char key[StringLengthPS+1], unsigned long long int llupar, struct avltree* AVL_Tree, bool PrintStatus);

// Удаление листа по значению
void AVL_RemoveLeaf(char key[StringLengthPS+1], struct avltree* AVL_Tree, bool PrintStatus);

// Поиск значения
bool AVL_FindMe(char key[StringLengthPS+1], struct avltree* AVL_Tree);
unsigned long long int AVL_FindMe_p(char key[StringLengthPS+1], struct avltree* AVL_Tree, bool PrintStatus);

// Печать дерева
void AVL_PrintMe(struct avltree* AVL_Tree);

// Сохранение дерева
void AVL_SaveTree(struct avltree* AVL_Tree,  bool PrintStatus);

// Загрузка дерева
void AVL_LoadTree(struct avltree* AVL_Tree,  bool PrintStatus);


#endif
```

**AVL_tree_slimrg.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "AVL_tree_slimrg.h"

// Структура строки
struct String{
    char* Text;
    unsigned short int count;
};

// Структура листа
struct avlleaf {
  struct String key;              // Ключ
  unsigned long long int llupar;  // Значение
  long int height;                // Высота
  struct avlleaf* left;          // Левый ребенок
  struct avlleaf* right;         // Правый ребенок
};

// Структура дерева
struct avltree {
    struct avlleaf* root;
};

// Создание дерева
struct avltree* AVL_Create() {
  struct avltree* AVL_Tree = malloc(sizeof(struct avltree));
  AVL_Tree->root = NULL;
  return AVL_Tree;
}

// Уничтожение дерева
void AVL_FreeAndNil(struct avltree* AVL_Tree) {
  // Переменные
  char tmpword[StringLengthPS+1];
  unsigned short int i; // Тикер (для циклов и т.д.)

  // Запускаем балалайку ^_^
  while (AVL_IsEmpty(AVL_Tree) == false) {
    for (i = 0; i <= AVL_Tree->root->key.count; i++) {
        tmpword[i] = AVL_Tree->root->key.Text[i];
    }
    AVL_RemoveLeaf(tmpword, AVL_Tree, false);
  }
}

// Проверка на пустоту
bool AVL_IsEmpty(struct avltree* AVL_Tree) {
  return (AVL_Tree->root == NULL);
}

// Инициализация листа
struct avlleaf* AVLLeaf_Create(char inputkey[StringLengthPS+1], unsigned long long int llupar) {

  // Переменные
  struct avlleaf* keim; // Лист
  unsigned short int i; // Тикер (для циклов и т.д.)


  // Начальная инициализация
  keim = malloc(sizeof(struct avlleaf));
  keim->right = keim->left = NULL;
  keim->llupar = llupar;

  // Сложная инициализация
  i = 0;
  while (inputkey[i] != 0) i++;
  keim->key.count = i;
  keim->key.Text = malloc(keim->key.count * sizeof(char));
  for (i = 0; i <= keim->key.count; i++) {
      keim->key.Text[i] =  inputkey[i];
  }

  keim->height = 0;
  return keim;
}

// Получение высоты листа
long int AVLLeaf_GetHeight(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {
  if (Leaf == NULL) return (-1); else return Leaf->height;
}

// Получение коэффицента балансировки
char AVLLeaf_GetBalance(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {
  return (AVLLeaf_GetHeight(Leaf->right) - AVLLeaf_GetHeight(Leaf->left));
}

// Проверка высоты
void AVLLeaf_CheckHeight(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {

  // Переменные
  long int left, right; // Дети листа Leaf

  left  = AVLLeaf_GetHeight(Leaf->left);
  right = AVLLeaf_GetHeight(Leaf->right);

  // Высота получается увеличением максимальной детской высоты на единицу
  if (left <= right)  Leaf->height = right + 1; else Leaf->height = left + 1;
}

// Малое леве вращение (Small Left)
struct avlleaf* AVL_rotation_SL(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {

  // Переменные
  struct avlleaf* aor; // Ось вращения (Axis Of Rotation)

  aor = Leaf->right;

  // Магия вращения... (Вжух...)
  Leaf->right = aor->left;
  aor->left   = Leaf;

  // Выправляем высоту
  AVLLeaf_CheckHeight(Leaf);
  AVLLeaf_CheckHeight(aor);

  return aor;
}

// Малое правое вращение (Small Right)
struct avlleaf* AVL_rotation_SR(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {

  // Переменные
  struct avlleaf* aor; // Ось вращения (Axis Of Rotation)

  aor = Leaf->left;

  // Магия вращения... (Вжух...)
  Leaf->left = aor->right;
  aor->right = Leaf;

  // Выправляем высоту
  AVLLeaf_CheckHeight(Leaf);
  AVLLeaf_CheckHeight(aor);

  return aor;
}

// Ребалансировка дерева
struct avlleaf* AVL_BalanceMe(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {

  // Переменные
  char balfac; // Коэффицент баласировки (от -2 до +2)


  balfac = AVLLeaf_GetBalance(Leaf);

  // Оцениваем баланс и выправляем его
  if (balfac < -1) {

    // Смотрим, требуется ли большое вращение
    if (AVLLeaf_GetBalance(Leaf->left) > 0) {
      Leaf->left = AVL_rotation_SL(Leaf->left);
    }

    return (AVL_rotation_SR(Leaf));

  } else if (balfac > 1) {

    // Смотрим, требуется ли большое вращение
    if (AVLLeaf_GetBalance(Leaf->right) < 0) {
      Leaf->right = AVL_rotation_SR(Leaf->right);
    }

    return (AVL_rotation_SL(Leaf));

  } else {  // Если нуль

    // Вращение НЕ требуется
    AVLLeaf_CheckHeight(Leaf);

    return Leaf;

  }
}

// Поиск места вставки и вставка
struct avlleaf* AVL_FindAndInsert(char key[StringLengthPS+1], unsigned long long int llupar, struct avlleaf* Leaf, bool PrintStatus) {
  // Если поддерево пустое
  if (Leaf == NULL) {

    if (PrintStatus) printf("OK\n");
    return AVLLeaf_Create(key, llupar);

  } else if (strcmp(key, Leaf->key.Text) < 0) {

    Leaf->left  = AVL_FindAndInsert(key, llupar, Leaf->left, PrintStatus);

  } else if (strcmp(key, Leaf->key.Text) > 0){

    Leaf->right = AVL_FindAndInsert(key, llupar, Leaf->right, PrintStatus);

  } else {

    if (PrintStatus) printf("Exist\n");

  }

  return AVL_BalanceMe(Leaf);

}

// Добавление листа (обертка над функцией выше)
void AVL_InsertLeaf(char key[StringLengthPS+1], unsigned long long int llupar, struct avltree* AVLTree, bool PrintStatus) {
  AVLTree->root = AVL_FindAndInsert(key, llupar, AVLTree->root, PrintStatus);
}

// Получение минимального значения
struct String AVL_GetMinKey(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {
  while (Leaf->left != NULL) Leaf = Leaf->left;
  return Leaf->key;
}

// Получение параметра у листа с минимальным значением
unsigned long long int AVL_GetMinVal(struct avlleaf* Leaf) {
  while (Leaf->left != NULL) Leaf = Leaf->left;
  return Leaf->llupar;
}

// Поиск и удаление
struct avlleaf* AVL_FindAndRemove(char key[StringLengthPS+1], struct avlleaf* Leaf, bool PrintStatus) {

  // Переменные
  struct avlleaf* child; // Служебная (для случаев с одним ребенком)
  char tmpkey[StringLengthPS+1];      // Временный контейнер для ключа
  unsigned short int i;  // Тикер (для циклов и т.д.)

  if (Leaf == NULL) {
    // Нет значения для удаления
    if (PrintStatus) printf("NoSuchWord\n");
    return NULL;

  } else if (strcmp(key, Leaf->key.Text) < 0) {

    Leaf->left = AVL_FindAndRemove(key, Leaf->left, PrintStatus);
    return AVL_BalanceMe(Leaf);

  } else if (strcmp(key, Leaf->key.Text) > 0) {

    Leaf->right = AVL_FindAndRemove(key, Leaf->right, PrintStatus);
    return AVL_BalanceMe(Leaf);

  } else { // Найдена позиция

    if (PrintStatus) printf("OK\n");
    // Анализ детей и перемещение
    if (Leaf->left != NULL && Leaf->right != NULL) {

      Leaf->key    =  AVL_GetMinKey(Leaf->right);
      Leaf->llupar =  AVL_GetMinVal(Leaf->right);

      for (i = 0; i <= Leaf->key.count; i++) {
          tmpkey[i] = Leaf->key.Text[i];
      }

      Leaf->right =   AVL_FindAndRemove(tmpkey, Leaf->right, PrintStatus);

      return AVL_BalanceMe(Leaf);

    } else if (Leaf->left != NULL) {

      // Есть только один ребенок (правый)

      child = Leaf->left;
      Leaf->key.count = 0;
      free(Leaf->key.Text);
      free(Leaf);
      return child;

    } else if (Leaf->right != NULL) {

       // Есть только один ребенок (левый)

      child = Leaf->right;
      Leaf->key.count = 0;
      free(Leaf->key.Text);
      free(Leaf);
      return child;

    } else {

      // Нет дитей - просто выкидываем
      Leaf->key.count = 0;
      free(Leaf->key.Text);
      free(Leaf);
      return NULL;

    }

  }

}

// Удаление из дерева (обертка над функцией выше)
void AVL_RemoveLeaf(char key[StringLengthPS+1], struct avltree* AVL_Tree, bool PrintStatus) {
  AVL_Tree->root = AVL_FindAndRemove(key, AVL_Tree->root, PrintStatus);
}

// Поиск элемента в дереве
bool AVL_FindMe(char key[StringLengthPS+1], struct avltree* AVL_Tree) {

  // Переменные
  struct avlleaf* CuP;

  CuP = AVL_Tree->root;
  while (CuP != NULL) {

    if (strcmp (key, CuP->key.Text) == 0) {

      return true;

    } else if (strcmp(key, CuP->key.Text) < 0) {

      CuP  = CuP->left;

    } else {

       CuP = CuP->right;

    }

  }

  return false;

}

// Еще один алгоритм поиска (удобнее для пользователя)
unsigned long long int AVL_FindMe_p(char key[StringLengthPS+1], struct avltree* AVL_Tree, bool PrintStatus){

  // Переменные
  struct avlleaf* CuP;

  CuP = AVL_Tree->root;
  while (CuP != NULL) {

    if (strcmp (key, CuP->key.Text) == 0) {

      if (PrintStatus){
          printf("OK: ");
          printf("%llu", (CuP->llupar));
          printf("\n");
      }
      return CuP->llupar;

    } else if (strcmp(key, CuP->key.Text) < 0) {

      CuP  = CuP->left;

    } else {

       CuP = CuP->right;

    }

  }

  if (PrintStatus) printf("NoSuchWord\n");
  return 0;

}

// Печать дерева
void AVL_print_rec(struct avlleaf* Leaf, long int lvl) {

  // Переменные
  int i;

  if (Leaf == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  AVL_print_rec(Leaf->left, lvl + 1);

  for (i = 0; i < lvl; i++) printf("\t");

  printf("%s", Leaf->key.Text);
  printf("%c", '|');
  printf("%llu", Leaf->llupar);
  printf("\n");

  AVL_print_rec(Leaf->right, lvl + 1);
}

// Печать дерева (обертка над функцией выше)
void AVL_PrintMe(struct avltree* AVL_Tree){
  if (AVL_Tree->root == NULL) {
    printf("EMPTY\n");
  } else {
    AVL_print_rec(AVL_Tree->root, 0);
  }
}

// Запись лист в файл
void AVL_LeafToFile(struct avlleaf* Leaf, FILE * file){
    if (Leaf == NULL) return;

    fwrite(&(Leaf->key.count), sizeof(unsigned short int), 1, file);
    fwrite(Leaf->key.Text, sizeof(char), Leaf->key.count+1, file);
    fwrite(&(Leaf->llupar), sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);

    AVL_LeafToFile(Leaf->right, file);
    AVL_LeafToFile(Leaf->left, file);
}

// Сохранение дерева
void AVL_SaveTree(struct avltree* AVL_Tree, bool PrintStatus){

    // Переменные
    char adress[1024];
    FILE *file = NULL;

    // Открытие файла
    scanf("%s", adress);
    file = fopen(adress, "wb+");
    if ((file == NULL)&&(PrintStatus)) printf("ERROR: Couldn't create file\n");
    if (file == NULL) return;

    // Запись дерева
    fwrite(&(UnCo), sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);
    AVL_LeafToFile(AVL_Tree->root, file);

    // Закрытие
    if (PrintStatus) printf("OK\n");
    fclose(file);
}

// Поиск места вставки и вставка
struct avlleaf* AVL_FindAndInsert_clean(char key[StringLengthPS+1], unsigned long long int llupar, struct avlleaf* Leaf, bool PrintStatus) {
  // Если поддерево пустое
  if (Leaf == NULL) {

    return AVLLeaf_Create(key, llupar);

  } else if (strcmp(key, Leaf->key.Text) < 0) {

    Leaf->left  = AVL_FindAndInsert_clean(key, llupar, Leaf->left, PrintStatus);

  } else if (strcmp(key, Leaf->key.Text) > 0){

    Leaf->right = AVL_FindAndInsert_clean(key, llupar, Leaf->right, PrintStatus);

  } else {

    if (PrintStatus) printf("ERROR: Broken File\n");

  }

  return Leaf;

}

// Добавление листа (обертка над функцией выше)
void AVL_InsertLeaf_clean(char key[StringLengthPS+1], unsigned long long int llupar, struct avltree* AVLTree, bool PrintStatus) {
  AVLTree->root = AVL_FindAndInsert_clean(key, llupar, AVLTree->root, PrintStatus);
}

// Загрузка листа из файла
void AVL_LeafFromFile(struct avltree* AVL_Tree, FILE * file){

    // Переменные
    char tmpkey[StringLengthPS+1];
    unsigned long long int tmpllupar;
    unsigned short int charcount;



    while (feof(file) == 0){
        fread(&charcount, sizeof(unsigned short int), 1, file);
        fread(tmpkey, sizeof(char), charcount+1, file);
        fread(&tmpllupar, sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);

        AVL_InsertLeaf_clean(tmpkey, tmpllupar, AVL_Tree, false);
    }
}

// Загрузка дерева
void AVL_LoadTree(struct avltree* AVL_Tree,  bool PrintStatus){

    // Переменные
    char adress[1024];
    FILE *file = NULL;
    unsigned long long int FileUnCo;

    // Открытие файла
    scanf("%s", adress);
    file = fopen(adress, "rb");
    if ((file == NULL)&&(PrintStatus)) printf("ERROR: Couldn't read file\n");
    if (file == NULL) return;

    // Тест совместимости
    fread(&FileUnCo, sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);
    if (UnCo != FileUnCo){
        printf("ERROR: Unsupported file\n");
        return;
    }

    // Уничтожаем ранее созданное дерево
    AVL_FreeAndNil(AVL_Tree);

    // Загружаем новое дерево
    AVL_LeafFromFile(AVL_Tree, file);

    // Закрытие
    if (PrintStatus) printf("OK\n");
    fclose(file);
}
```

**settings_slimrg.h**

```
#ifndef settings_h
#define settings_h
/* Settings */

//  Настройка ввода
const unsigned int StringLengthPS = 256; // Длина строки (в символах)

// Настройка отладки
const bool debug_pauseonclose = true; // Следует ли делать паузу перед выходом

// Номер сборки
const unsigned long long int UnCo = 115700744534137162;

#endif
```

**MakeFile**

```
all:
    gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -Werror -Wno-sign-compare main.c AVL_tree_slimrg.c -lm -o lb2
```

**Лог** (здесь main.c заменен на lb2.c)

```
gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -Werror -Wno-sign-compare lb2.c AVL_tree_slimrg.c -lm -o lb2
/tmp/cc4upHwG.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `StringLengthPS'
/tmp/ccORqDAb.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cc4upHwG.o:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `debug_pauseonclose'
/tmp/ccORqDAb.o:(.rodata+0x4): first defined here
/tmp/cc4upHwG.o:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `UnCo'
/tmp/ccORqDAb.o:(.rodata+0x8): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const unsigned int StringLengthPS = 256; // Длина строки (в символах)
const bool debug_pauseonclose = true; // Следует ли делать паузу перед выходом
const unsigned long long int UnCo = 115700744534137162;
```

Раз у вас константы в хедере, то они копируются в каждый .c файл, который этот хедер инклудит - отсюда `multiple definition`.

Решение:

Либо сделать переменные `static` - тогда каждый файл получит свою копию каждой переменной,
либо заменить переменные на `#define`.

Answer (score 6):

В отличие от С++, в языке С `const` объекты имеют *внешнее связывание* по умолчанию. Их нельзя определять в заголовочных файлах.

Либо явно придайте им *внутреннее связывание*, т.е. определяйте их как `static const`, либо идите по традиционному пути: в заголовочный файл кладите, `extern const` без инициализатора, а в один из `.c` файлов кладите ваши определения.

В вашем случае можно также просто заменить ваши константы на макросы или enum.